# How can I see what ports are open on my machine?

Tags: networking, server

I would like to see what ports are open on my machine, e.g. what ports my machine is listening on. E.g. port 80 if I have installed a web server, and so on.

Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

## [nmap](https://packages.ubuntu.com/nmap) ([install](https://apt.ubuntu.com/p/nmap))

[Nmap ("Network Mapper")](https://nmap.org/) is a free and open source utility for network exploration or security auditing.

Use `nmap 192.168.1.33` for internal PC or `nmap external IP address`.

More information `man nmap`.

[Zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/) is the official GUI frontend.

Comment: Thanks, `nmap localhost` worked great.

Comment: Remember that there is a difference between `nmap localhost` and `nmap 192.168.0.3` (or what ever you machine IP is)

Comment: If you want a nice GUI for nmap, you can try 'zenmap'.

Comment: I think netstat is a better answer to this. netstat will list what the system is listening on directly, and without using an additional application or doing unnecessary calls over localhost or thought the network.

Comment: This is stupid. If you have access to the computer, just use `netstat -ln`. You'll instantly see all the open ports.

Comment: `nmap localhost` didn't find services that were bound only to localhost. For example, I run `influxd` with `bind-address:localhost:8086`. That didn't show up in `sudo nmap localhost`, but did show up in `sudo netstat -tulpn`.

Comment: I sort of think nmap is overkill for just seeing ports on one's own computer...

Answer (score 399):

I've always used this:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp
```

If the `netstat` command is not available, install it with:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Comment: `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` ... use `sudo` otherwise ... pid will not be printed.

Comment: `-l` already filters for listening. `grep LISTEN` won't help beyond hiding 2 lines of header information.

Comment: `-t`: tcp, `-l`: listening socket, `-p`: show pid and program name, `-n`: print `127.0.0.1:80` instead of `localhost:http`. Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

Comment: install `netstat` with `sudo apt-get install net-tools`

Comment: If you use the pipe and the command takes a long time, check it hasn't just filtered out the password prompt and is waiting for you to type, if you haven't sudoed recently!

Comment: The expanded command is `sudo netstat --tcp --listening --programs --numeric`. There’s no need to use `grep` unless you want to eliminate column headers.

Comment: @PatrickDark - I've had to script that in for a lot of my use, so I didn't need the headers in my case (extra noise), but that's a good point.

Answer (score 80):

Other good ways to find out what ports are listenting and what your firewall rules are:

- `sudo netstat -tulpn`
- `sudo ufw status`

Comment: I change the answer to `nmap` again, the usability of `netstat` is crap.

Comment: @Jonas: see my comment under the nmap answer. It won't list services that bind to localhost only.

Answer (score 32):

To list open ports use the `netstat` command.

For example:

```
    $ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5452/dnsmasq    
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1037/cupsd      
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1037/cupsd
```

In the above example three services are bound to the loopback address.

IPv4 services bound to the loopback address "127.0.0.1" are only available on the local machine. The equivalent loopback address for IPv6 is "::1". The IPv4 address "0.0.0.0" means "any IP address", which would mean that other machines could potentially connect to any of the locally configured network interfaces on the specific port.

Another method is to use the `lsof` command:

```
    $ sudo lsof -nP -i | grep LISTEN
    cupsd     1037   root    9u  IPv6  11276      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
    cupsd     1037   root   10u  IPv4  11277      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
    dnsmasq   5452 nobody    5u  IPv4 212707      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:53 (LISTEN)
```

For more details see `man netstat` or `man lsof`.

Comment: I thought the `-l` option was to list `LISTEN`ing ports. So the grep would be superfluous here?!

Comment: thanks for the hint with `lsof` which is available in a fresh Ubuntu installation, so could be used if you face some connection issues and can't use `apt` yet.

Answer (score 27):

This is enough to show that there is a process listening on IP address `0.0.0.0` (needed so it will reply to any request) on port 80 (standard web server port number). In my case this shows it is the web server `lighttpd`

```
$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN          2495/lighttpd
```

If you later want to make sure that the only thing you allow through your firewall is port 80 I often use ShieldsUp from www.grc.com to perform a firewall test.

Answer (score 11):

`sudo iptables -L` will list the port rules for your pc.
Note that if you are using ufw or shorewall firewalls the output maybe be hard to read.
In that case rather use `sudo ufw status` for example.

This is not very useful on its own as even if a port is open access will still be denied if there is no process listening on that port.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for continuous monitoring of ports for server machines or local  I think you can also use graphical version of nmap i.e Zenmap for more detailed version

Zenmap is the official graphical user interface (GUI) for the Nmap Security Scanner.

Supports available (Linux, Windows, Mac OS X, BSD, etc.)

Have a look to this tool view:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In latest Linux distro, most probably you won't find `netstat` command anymore.

```
$ netstat

Command 'netstat' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install net-tools

$
```

However, if you want to use it, go ahead and install it with `sudo apt install net-tools` command.

Fyi, netstat is obsolete (refer to the man page), so you should use `ss` intead of `netstat`.

> This program is obsolete.  Replacement for netstat is ss.
> Replacement    for  netstat -r is ip route.  Replacement for netstat
> -i is ip -s link.    Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr.

E.g.

```
$ ss -lnt
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      5                 127.0.1.1:53                       *:*
LISTEN     0      128               127.0.0.1:631                      *:*
LISTEN     0      128                     ::1:631                     :::*
```

Description

> ss = another utility to investigate sockets
>
> -l, --listening
> Display only listening sockets (these are omitted by default).
>
> -n, --numeric
> Do not try to resolve service names.
>
> -t, --tcp
> Display TCP sockets.

Answer (score 3):

ss:
    Print:
        network connections
        routing tables
        interface statistics
        masquerade connections
        multicast memberships

```
Install:
    sudo apt install net-tools

Example:
    ~$ ss -ntlp | grep LISTEN
    >
    LISTEN   0        4096             127.0.0.53%lo:53              0.0.0.0:*                                                                                      
    LISTEN   0        5                    127.0.0.1:631             0.0.0.0:*                                                                                      
    LISTEN   0        5                        [::1]:631                [::]:*                                                                                      
    LISTEN   0        50          [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:9614                  *:*
```

Comment: Are you sure? net-tools provide netstat. [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) provide ss. Check with `dpkg -S $(which ss)`

Answer (score 1):

assuming u wanna check port 3000:
`netstat -na | grep 3000`