# Why do these errors appear while running fake run-fake-gps.sh?

Tags: command-line, networking, python, gps

I am working on a `dronekit` follow_me project. So in one terminal, I am running `python follow_me.py` and in another terminal running `run-fake-gps.sh`. Then an error appears as below:

```
Sending fake GPS data
 Processing fake-gps-data.log
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port 2947, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv6 port 2947, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
```

Maybe these errors are causing my `follow_me.py` to stop before ending.

To stop the process I ran

`start-stop-daemon -K --name gpsd`

When I ran `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 2947`

I got below:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2947    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1/init          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:2947          :::*        LISTEN      1/init
```

While running python follow_me.py it automatically connects to

```
Connecting to vehicle on: tcp:127.0.0.1:5760
```

I did run in a new terminal

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

The output appears as follows:

> tcp  0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1775/dnsmasq
>   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631     0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN     832/cupsd
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5760      0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      15355/apm
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5762      0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      15355/apm
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5763      0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      15355/apm
>   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2947    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      1/init
>   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      836/mongod
>   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      998/mysqld
>   tcp6       0      0 :::80             :::*        LISTEN      1197/apache2
>   tcp6       0      0 :::21             :::*        LISTEN      961/vsftpd
>   tcp6       0      0 ::1:631           :::*        LISTEN      832/cupsd
>   tcp6       0      0 ::1:2947          :::*        LISTEN      1/init

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure you have stopped gpsd before running the `run-fake-gps.sh` script. If the problem happens again, collect the complete outpur of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 2947`. Then edit your question to include that output.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command while you run `python follow_me.py`:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

[How can I see what ports are open on my machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9368/how-can-i-see-what-ports-are-open-on-my-machine)

Then you should see your python `follow_me.py` is using port 2947.
You can solve this by using another port in one of both scripts.

Comment: Problem: gpsd-aware applications expect gpsd data to be on port 2947. There's no negotiation or backup for that port. Better to find out which application is blocking use of the port.

Comment: Thanks, for all the answers. Still trying to solve the issues. I have edited the post with new output. Please have a look.